# Function for diagonalizing a vector.

Tags: matrices, algebra-precalculus, vector-spaces

I was playing around whith the idea of *what operation (function) should I perform (apply) over a vector* $\mathbf{a} = (a_1,a_2, \ldots, a_N)^T \in \mathbb{R}^N$ *to come up with the following matrix*:

$$ A = 
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
a_1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0  & a_2 & \cdots &  0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & a_N
\end{array} \right)?
$$ *i.e, how can I* **diagonalize** *my vector* $\mathbf{a}$.

This is my approach, but first I must apologize for my very rusty linear-applications-knowhow. That being said, I was wondering that, if there exist the following relation between $\mathbf{a}$ and $A$ :

$$ A \, \mathbf{1}  = \mathbf{a},$$ where $\mathbf{1}$ is a $n \times 1$ column vector filled with ones in its entries, then I can trivially solve for $A$ in terms of the pseudoinverse of $\mathbf{a}$ as follows:

$$ A = \left[ \mathbf{1} \, \mathbf{a}^T \, (\mathbf{a} \, \mathbf{a}^T)^{-1} \right]^{-1}, $$ so this would become my desired $A = f(\mathbf{a})$. Unfortunately, Matlab has wisely warned me that $\det{(\mathbf{a}\, \mathbf{a}^T)} = 0$ (which I can't formally see why), so the above formula makes no sense.

I'm run out of ideas right now. Someone can help me?

Thanks in advance and

Cheers!

**Edit 1**: of course, I should have mentioned that I'm aware of the existence of the command *diag* in Matlab.

Comment: I don't understand. What about defining $f(\mathbf a)=A$?

Comment: Hi @GitGud, I'm searching for something more 'exotic'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $\mathbf{e}_i$ be the standard basis vector with $1$ in the $i$th position and $0$ otherwise. Then

$$ A =  \sum_{i = 1}^{N} (\mathbf{e}_i \mathbf{e}_i^T) (\mathbf{e}_i^T \mathbf{a}) .$$

(Note that $\mathbf{e}_i^T \mathbf{a} = a_i$, and $\mathbf{e}_i\mathbf{e}_i^T$ is the matrix with $1$ in the $i,i$ position and $0$ otherwise.)

Comment: In MatLab just use [diag](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diag.html).

Comment: Awesome. I will edit my post within a few hours with an extension of this.

Answer (score 1):

The matrix $aa^T$ has rank $1$, that is why the determinant is $0$.

If you want a matlab function to transform the vector into a matrix, just write

```
A=diag(a)
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment @5xum, see my edit. Now I see why $\det(\mathbf{a} \mathbf{a}^T) = 0$.

Comment: @Dmoreno Then I do not understand what you are asking. You want a function that turns a vector into the diagonal vector, and you have it, so what is the question?

Comment: I'm seeking for a function which only involves elementary operations to get my desired result. My question is therefore equivalent to 'what is the mathematical equivalent to the diag function in Matlab?', which Willie Wong has already answered. Cheers!

Comment: I understand notw, I guess willie gave you what you need then. Cheers.